# How to use command to compile applescript like "Compile" from "Applescript Editor"

Tags: applescript

I have two apple scripts:

parent.scpt:
`property a:1`

child.scpt:
    `property parent:load script POSIX file ".../parent.scpt"
    return a`

I change the value of a to "2" in parent.scpt ,run "sudo osacompile .../child.scpt" then "sudo osascript .../child.scpt"
it still gets the value "1" , but if I "Compile" child.scpt from "AppleScript Editor" , I can get the right value "2"

Did I miss something? How to achieve this using command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties are persistent until you recompile the script. If you load a script file while setting a property it is done at compile time and not at run time. This mean a copy of the script is stored and the property doesn't relate to the file. The reason why it works with script editor is that the file is recompiled again, which means the parent.scpt is loaded to the latest version again.

I won't recommend to load parent objects, it's better to load child objects. Now you start at the bottom of the parenting chain which is better to build up the object tree starting at the root object.

Looking at you're code you're trying to add objects in your object tree dynamically. One way to do that is this:

parent.scpt:

```
property name : "I'm the parent"
property b : 100

set theChildLib to load script POSIX file "/Users/shortname/Desktop/child.scpt"
set theChild to theChildLib's newChildObject(me)
return {theChild's parent's name, theChild's name, theChild's a, theChild's b}
```

child.scpt:

```
on newChildObject(_parent)
    script childObject
        property parent : _parent
        property name : "I'm the child"
        property a : 2
    end script
    return childObject
end newChildObject
```

As you can see I can call the parent from the child. When I call a property that doesn't exists in the object it will follow the parenting chain.

Comment: figured out a simple solution if someone is following my example : copy code from child.scpt to a plain text file says child.txt , run "sudo osacompile -o child.scpt child.txt" every time before run "sudo osascript child.scpt" , or just run "sudo osascript child.txt"